# Выводить данные, если количество строк в результирующем SQL-запросе больше нуля

Tags: php, html, sql, select

Люди добрые, завис на простейшей задаче.

Делаю `select` запрос к БД с параметрами. Далее вывожу полученный результат в виде выпадающего списка. Но с некоторой долей вероятности - результат может быть пустым. В этом случае `mysqli_fetch_assoc` соответственно - ругается. Туплю - не знаю куда поставить проверку на то, что из БД что-то было получено.

Немного рабочего кода(спасибо Алексей Шиманский за напоминание):

```
<?
$sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM guests2order WHERE oid="'.$_SESSION['oid'].'"');
$row_num = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if($row_num != '0'){
echo '<select>';
while($guests = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
echo '<option value="'.$guests['id'].'">'.$guests['name'].'</option>';
}
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Соответственно хочется, что бы если из БД ничего не получено - `<select>...</select>` - вообще не выводился.

(Если проверять на пустоту `$sql` - то оно равно `TRUE`, если был вообще получен ответ от БД - даже пустой.)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.num-rows.php  ... если количество 0 - то `return`

Comment: Точно, забыл про это дело, спасибо)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский работает только с буферизованным результирующим набором

Comment: @rjhdby по умолчанию как раз буферезированный. А также запрос вида `$db->query($query)` равнозначен `$db->query($query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT)`, который является буферезированным

Comment: @rjhdby вообще понятно, что следует использовать адекватный драйвер для работы с БД, в котором предусмотрены и ошибки в запросе и возвращение 0 количества данных ну и подготовленные выражения. Чтобы вот так вот не извращаться))

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM guests2order WHERE oid="'.$_SESSION['oid'].'"');

$hasValues = false;
if($guests = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    echo '<select>';
    echo '<option value="'.$guests['id'].'">'.$guests['name'].'</option>';
    $hasValues = true;
}
while($guests = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$guests['id'].'">'.$guests['name'].'</option>';
}
if($hasValues) echo '</select>';
```

1) Проверка `if(!empty($guests))` не нужна, поскольку `mysqli_fetch_assoc` возвращает либо массив с данными, либо false, при котором цикл дальше не пойдет

2) Старайтесь никогда не использовать подобный способ создания SQL-запроса. Используйте [подготовленные выражения](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.mysqli-stmt.php)